# Optional Elements in XML Deserialization

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, serialization

I am adding some properties to a class in an existing class that I would like to be considered optional for the XML Deserializer.  I've added the IsNullable parameter as well as the Specified properties to no avail.  My code looks like this:

```
<XmlElement("name")>
Public Property Name As String
<XmlElement("car", IsNullable:=True)>
Public Property Car As String

<XmlIgnore>
Public ReadOnly Property CarSpecified As Boolean
    Get
        Return Car <> String.Empty
    End Get
End Property
```

And the XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Class>
    <name>Test</name>
</Class>
```

I get an exception with the message "Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: value"

Comment: One comment I have is that I prefer using `String.IsNullOrEmpty(Car)` to using `Car <> String.Empty`. Same result, but nice in places where null would result in an exception and String.Empty wouldn't.

Comment: Normally I use String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace or String.IsNUllOrEmpty but I wrote this up pretty quickly as an example so I went with the old standby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to provide more code. Based on the code you have shown, I do not see a problem (this executes without errors and shows correct values):

```
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

Module Module1

   Sub Main()

      Dim xd = _
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
         <Owner>
            <name>Test</name>
         </Owner>

      Dim xds As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Owner))
      Using xr As New System.IO.StringReader(xd.ToString())
         Dim o = DirectCast(xds.Deserialize(xr), Owner)
         Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}", o.Name, o.Car, o.CarSpecified)
      End Using
   End Sub
End Module

Public Class Owner
   <XmlElement("name")>
   Public Property Name As String
   <XmlElement("car", IsNullable:=True)>
   Public Property Car As String

   <XmlIgnore>
   Public ReadOnly Property CarSpecified As Boolean
      Get
         Return Car <> String.Empty
      End Get
   End Property
End Class
```

Comment: My problem was not in the serialization as I first thought, and researching your reply led me to the actual problem where I was trying to search a IEnumerable for an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Public Property Car As String?` - the question mark will ensure the property is nullable.

Edit: Try the following:

```
Public ReadOnly Property CarSpecified As Boolean
Get
    Return Car isnot nothing
End GetEnd Property
```

Comment: Strings are implicitly Nullable in VB.Net. I would add, however, that if the sample code is not faithful to the original code, and some value type is being used there instead of a string, then this is probably the answer.

Comment: In VB.Net comparing a string to nothing with the <> operator does not cause an error, so, although it is advisable to use `IsNot Nothing` or `Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Car)` it would not solve the problem here.

Comment: You can't add the nullable (?) type to string because it is not a value type.